Inno Setup - number of displayed included files
In my Inno Setup script I'm including files
#include "commons.iss"
#include "custom_messages.iss"
#include "code_utils.iss"
#include "code_connstr.iss"
#include "code_checks.iss"
#include "idp.iss"
#include "code_pages.iss"
#include "code_install.iss"
#include "code_legacy.iss"
#include "code_commons.iss"
#include "code_uninstall.iss"

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard();
...

No matter what lenght of names of those files is, the number of opened files in upper bar is limited to 10.
Any ideas, how to increase this?
I'd like to split my code to more readable files and keep the option to see them all in the upper bar.
I've checked UI, registry and main Inno Setup files if somewhere this configuration can be found, but no luck.
The only thing is in Options - Automaticaly open #include files
My version is 6.2.2


No such limits are mentioned in the documentation. Perhaps you should ask the developer.

In the next version the limit is 20 instead of 10, and tabs are closeable. See http://jrsoftware.github.io/issrc/whatsnew.htm
I don't know when this version will be released.
Greetings,
Martijn Laan
6.3.0-dev (?)
Support for #include files improved

The Compiler IDE now opens up to 20 #include files in tabs, instead of up to 10.

